# F# make member value based on member function

Tags: f#, member-functions, member-variables

I have made a member function in a class. Afterwards I want to make a member value that is set to the result of this member function.

```
type MyType() = 
  member this.drawFilledPlanet(xCoord:int, yCoord:int, pWidth:int, pHeight:int, color) =
    let brush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(color)
    this.window.Paint.Add(fun e -> 
      e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, xCoord, yCoord, pWidth, pHeight))

  member val theSun = drawFilledPlanet(350,350,100,100, this.yellow)
```

I am getting the error that `drawFilledPlanet` is not defined.

Can someone tell me what is up?

Comment: Missing `this.` in front of `drawFilledPlanet`.

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: if i do that it errors the namespace or module 'this' is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `drawFilledPlanet` is a member function, it needs a class instance on which it's to be called. If you're calling it from another member function, you would use that member's definition to name the current instance:

```
member this.f() = this.drawFilledPlanet ...
```

In your case, however, since you're defining a `member val`, you don't have that opportunity. In this situation, you can name the current instance at the very top of the class declaration:

```
type MyType() as this =
    ...
    member val theSun = this.drawFilledPlanet ...
```

One thing I'd like to point out is that this definition may not have the effect that you expect. If you define `theSun` this way, the `drawFilledPlanet` method will only get executed once at class initialization, not every time `theSun` is accessed. Did you intend that? If no, then you need to change the definition. If yes, then why do you need this definition at all?